# Why does int('.0') give ValueError?

Tags: python, floating-point, type-conversion, int, valueerror

I pass float number as string format in `int('.0')`

0.0 is valid floating point number, so why it is giving error?

Comment: Because **integers** are not floating-point.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
int(2.1) gives 2 in return. so  int convert it into int.

Comment: `int('2.1')` returns a value error too. Similarly `int(0.1)` returns 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
>   bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix
>   base. Optionally, the literal can be preceded by + or - (with no space
>   in between) and surrounded by whitespace.

So it gives you `ValueError` because the string `'.0'` does not represent an integer literal.

Comment: @Nishant: Notice how it **doesn't** say "the literal can be preceded by a `.`".

Answer (score 2):

Because you can type cast one step at a time. For example you can convert float to int or string to int. Not a floating point string which here is 2steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you remove the quotes and make it a float like:

```
int(.1)
```

But strings don't work if inside the string is a float, because they will think it's a number and will break saying `'.'` is not a numeric value, also the reason the above works is because:

```
>>> .1
0.1
>>>
```

And:

```
float(0.1)
```

Works.

Note that even a real float in a string can't be converted into an integer:

```
>>> int('3.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    int('3.1')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.1'
```